# Размеры и отображение imageview и imagebutton

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! При копировании картинки в папку mipmap система предлагает 4 варианта сохранения данной картинки: hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. Вопрос простой: что означают эти 4 параметра и влияют ли они на отображение image-элемента на экранах с разными диагоналями?

Comment: Как насчет официальной документации? https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: влияют, есть еще xxxhdpi

Comment: А если я хочу, чтобы несколько imagebutton отображались одинаково хорошо как на экране в 4,5 дюйма так и на экране 5,5 дюймов то как быть в этом случае? Увеличивать размеры изображений и сохранить несколько копий изображения с разными параметрами (hdpi, mdpi...)?

Comment: да, под каждый размер экрана делаете свой ресурс и сохраняете в папку с соответствующим квалификатором